# How to classify a batch of images with the pre trained TensorFlow Inception network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I use the latest pre trained [Inception model](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0). I use sliding window technique to find different objects on the image (around 3000 windows per image). It takes too much time to process window by window as a sequence. I want to run prediction in parallel. How can I do this?

`image_data` should be the list.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0') 

    test_img = cv2.resize(img3[window[0][1]:window[1][1], window[0][0]:window[1][0]], dsize=(299,299), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    np_image_data = np.asarray(test_img)
    np_image_data=cv2.normalize(np_image_data.astype('float'), None, -0.5, .5, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    image_data = np.expand_dims(np_image_data,axis=0)  

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'Mul:0': image_data})
```

Comment: Did you advance here ? I have the same problem ... i think we have to use batches .. but i dont know how ..

Comment: still no answer. I have switched to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection